# What I am missing that in ExifInterface?

Tags: android, interface

I need to find the rotate rate from the gallery in the Android.

So I use the Exifinterface, but I got the error 'FileNotFoundException'.

When I debug my source,

img_path value : storage/emulated/0/DCIM/나/20171222_160744.jpg

This is the source.

Intent

```
    public void doTakeAlbumAction() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
    intent.setType(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.CONTENT_TYPE);
    intent.setData(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE_SELECT_IMAGE);
}
```

and then

```
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode != getActivity().RESULT_OK)
        return;

    if (requestCode == REQ_CODE_SELECT_IMAGE) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
        {
            try {

                // 180113 - 1.5v 적용 필요.
                String img_path = getImagePathToUri(data.getData());

                try {
                    ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(img_path);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
         }
      }
```

Comment: You asked this already in your other post. So why post again? You could better have searched on this site as your problem has been discussed a hundred times allready.

Comment: `getImagePathToUri()` You mean getImagePathFromUri() i think. You should not try to do that as it will mostly fail. On Android 7+ ExifInterface will accept an InputStream which you can directly open for the uri. On other systems you should first make a copy on the file system so you can use a file path. As said: has been discussed a hundred times already. Pleae read more.